# Sending HTML form via AJAX to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, cordova

I'm working on phonegap, basically its like making mobileapps crossplatform by using HTML, JS and CSS. On the device i currently have the JS and the HTML (form) in same document.

What I'm trying to do is to pass email and password to my server, and then process it there through a login. I've tested the login script on the server and it works with hardcoded data. So I'm guessing somewhere when sending the data from the device its failing.. I'm fairly new to JS too.

I tried to hardcode the data in the AJAX but it doesnt seem to work. Preferebly I would like to use something like var pdata = $('#form').serialize(); or something else if its better.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Forgot to say that the PHP on the server auto submits by using JS when $_POST is set (isset)

**The form**

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="dologin()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Epost</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="" placeholder="Epost">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="password">Passord</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="" placeholder="Passord">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me">
        Husk meg
        </label>
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
</form>
```

**The javascript**

```
<script>
        function dologin() {
            //var pdata = $('#form').serialize();
            //alert(pdata);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {email:"test@test.no",password:"test"},
                url: 'LINK',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function() {                 
                    alert("error");
                } 
            });
            return false;
        };
</script>
```

**The PHP**

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <!-- {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }} -->
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["email"])) echo $_POST['email'];?>">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }} -->
        <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["password"])) echo $_POST['password'];?>">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to hit your server via through phonegap?
If no then please check your config.xml for white list urls - change access control property to

access origin = "*"

Hopeful you will be able to hit your server with data.

Comment: I'm unsure if I'm able to hit it or not how can I check this/debug, but access origin="*" is added, and also my domain incl. subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use weinre to debug your app. That way you will be able to see if the request was placed from the app or not.
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Comment: I moved the whole thing to the server, so now the server sends to the PHP on the server, it still doesnt work. I can't seem to start the ajax for some reason now. It wont even give me an error message. Alert("error"); which it did before..